# highstock minRange and color doesn't work on iOS app

Tags: jquery, html, ios, highcharts

I'm trying to set minimum range to display in highstock basic-live graph. It doesn't show data for Q mode (3 months). I referred here: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minRange

And examined this sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/minrange/

Below you can see my html file.
Why it doesn't show Q data? I send data from obj-c properly.
I also want to set colors of the lines on my graph. But it doesn't work either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>IH Technology</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/ihtechnology/Desktop/chart_deneme/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/ihtechnology/Desktop/chart_deneme/css/result-light.css">
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var serviceDataURL = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:83/get_item_data_ios?generic=CHANGEME";


            $(function() {

                Highcharts.setOptions({
                    colors: ['#2f7ed8','#8bbc21','#1aadce','#492970','#910000']
                });
                $.getJSON(serviceDataURL, function(data) {
                    // Create the chart
                    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
                        chart : {
                            renderTo : 'container'
                        },
                        navigation: {
                            buttonOptions: {
                                enabled: false,
                                width: 60
                            }
                        },
                        rangeSelector : {
                            buttonSpacing: 20,
                            buttonTheme: { // styles for Q,Y,YTD,ALL buttons
                                fill: 'none',
                                stroke: 'none',
                                'stroke-width': 15,
                                style: {
                                    color: '#039',
                                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                                },
                                states: {
                                    hover: {},
                                    select: {
                                        fill: '#039',
                                            style: {
                                                color: 'white'
                                            }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                minRange: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
                            },
                            selected : 3,
                            inputDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
                            inputEditDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
                            buttons:[
                                {
                                    type: 'month',
                                    count: 3,
                                    text: 'QQ'
                                },

                                {
                                    type: 'year',
                                    count: 1,
                                    text: 'YY'
                                },

                                {
                                    type: 'ytd',
                                    text: 'YTD'
                                },

                                {
                                    type: 'all',
                                    text: 'ALL'
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                        title : {
                            text : 'My Total Market'
                        },
                        credits: {
                            text: " ",
                            href: " ",
                        },
                        series : [{
                            name : 'Total Market',
                            data : arr,
                            tooltip: {
                                valueDecimals: 2
                            }
                        }],
                        exporting: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }, function(chart){
                            // apply the date pickers
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $('input.highcharts-range-selector').attr('readonly',1);
                                $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#'+chart.options.chart.renderTo))
                            },0)
                        });
                });

            });

                //]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What i  want its colors to look like: [image]

What it looks like: [image]

Demo data:

> [{"data": [[1199142000000, 2119674091.9100101], [1201820400000, 1939006129.3], [1204498800000, 1803635681.54], [1207004400000, 2129465095.1900001], [1209679200000, 1899714591.3800001], [1212271200000, 1896459540.5399899], [1214949600000, 2065013294.76], [1217541600000, 1825374185.27], [1220220000000, 2074823669.6099999], [1222898400000, 2116137141.1500001], [1225490400000, 1896242246.9200001], [1228172400000, 2033699918.5799999], [1230764400000, 2075073182.72], [1233442800000, 1840492669.4100001], [1236121200000, 2052730509.28], [1238540400000, 2077889469.5699999], [1241215200000, 1941841063.4400001], [1243807200000, 1969931496.3499899], [1246485600000, 2165285937.9699998], [1249077600000, 1954216841.23], [1251756000000, 2144279940.1900001], [1254434400000, 2198252662.8400002], [1257026400000, 2123911321.05], [1259708400000, 2146888381.96], [1262300400000, 2047968058.0], [1264978800000, 1979344944.1400001], [1267657200000, 2283709523.25], [1270076400000, 2144962961.3699901], [1272751200000, 2020742426.1400001], [1275343200000, 2110035420.49], [1278021600000, 2216362449.6300001], [1280613600000, 2043748069.49], [1283292000000, 2275795926.5900002], [1285970400000, 2160471715.5099902], [1288562400000, 2183973077.71], [1291244400000, 2170763356.20999], [1293836400000, 2142998271.46], [1296514800000, 2027281231.0599999], [1299193200000, 2202357111.8699999], [1301612400000, 2105630081.8699999], [1304287200000, 2298973085.7199998], [1306879200000, 2045854135.49], [1309557600000, 2228587748.1900001], [1312149600000, 2188917461.6599998], [1314828000000, 2269930852.8600001], [1317506400000, 2206994937.96], [1320098400000, 2258958927.9699998], [1322780400000, 2212829574.4000001], [1325372400000, 2253521938.71], [1328050800000, 2137224208.54], [1330729200000, 2274466272.2600002], [1333234800000, 2169985543.6900001], [1335909600000, 2230806922.6499901], [1338501600000, 2173467574.93999], [1341180000000, 2298072309.8499999], [1343772000000, 2172495356.4099998], [1346450400000, 2141606500.1199999], [1349128800000, 2434601545.3699999], [1351720800000, 2332058917.1599998], [1354402800000, 2141214271.3399899], [1356994800000, 2467266994.3600001], [1359673200000, 2213255518.3500099], [1362351600000, 2245979481.0900002], [1364770800000, 2451972706.4699898], [1367445600000, 2270787936.9300098], [1370037600000, 2217413938.76999], [1372716000000, 2542403950.9299898], [1375308000000, 2215359948.5399899], [1377986400000, 2344617276.4000001], [1380664800000, 2545581329.6700001], [1383256800000, 2381924297.1599898], [1385938800000, 2342226689.4099998], [1388530800000, 2591565871.29], [1391209200000, 2338993235.7199998], [1393887600000, 2432710893.7899899], [1396306800000, 2527936616.0999999]]}, {"data": [[1199142000000, 73930279.299999997], [1201820400000, 67821438.269999996], [1204498800000, 64365379.18], [1207004400000, 79045118.290000007], [1209679200000, 69487117.819999993], [1212271200000, 60566517.329999998], [1214949600000, 66888014.57], [1217541600000, 56103074.68], [1220220000000, 60627073.909999996], [1222898400000, 68149766.620000005], [1225490400000, 59284806.280000001], [1228172400000, 66064862.380000003], [1230764400000, 63444528.399999999], [1233442800000, 55890456.880000003], [1236121200000, 62720602.869999997], [1238540400000, 68204877.109999999], [1241215200000, 62730499.490000002], [1243807200000, 62867029.200000003], [1246485600000, 70117287.200000003], [1249077600000, 59528505.049999997], [1251756000000, 63915590.939999998], [1254434400000, 70342577.730000004], [1257026400000, 69995139.730000004], [1259708400000, 71713702.209999993], [1262300400000, 64170773.68], [1264978800000, 63884730.170000002], [1267657200000, 70381065.659999996], [1270076400000, 67993051.75], [1272751200000, 64663996.219999999], [1275343200000, 68206263.209999993], [1278021600000, 70826224.010000005], [1280613600000, 65216514.43], [1283292000000, 71504816.109999999], [1285970400000, 73352433.890000001], [1288562400000, 75468795.760000005], [1291244400000, 77513532.769999996], [1293836400000, 72205311.219999999], [1296514800000, 66212342.659999996], [1299193200000, 72045739.489999995], [1301612400000, 71326217.370000005], [1304287200000, 75380528.120000005], [1306879200000, 65781358.060000002], [1309557600000, 70953373.099999994], [1312149600000, 64420954.479999997], [1314828000000, 64825960.329999998], [1317506400000, 65919035.020000003], [1320098400000, 66664940.170000002], [1322780400000, 63891177.210000001], [1325372400000, 64787127.859999999], [1328050800000, 58200756.609999999], [1330729200000, 63375060.630000003], [1333234800000, 51597983.770000003], [1335909600000, 47135005.689999998], [1338501600000, 47535389.950000003], [1341180000000, 48121417.030000001], [1343772000000, 43630900.350000001], [1346450400000, 41834361.549999997], [1349128800000, 47788033.009999998], [1351720800000, 44647087.450000003], [1354402800000, 40230617.350000001], [1356994800000, 42538322.100000001], [1359673200000, 38086979.439999998], [1362351600000, 39306335.840000004], [1364770800000, 43922677.759999998], [1367445600000, 40207060.869999997], [1370037600000, 36659809.909999996], [1372716000000, 40690280.659999996], [1375308000000, 35487838.560000002], [1377986400000, 37164577.130000003], [1380664800000, 42919817.479999997], [1383256800000, 40280126.079999998], [1385938800000, 39720262.109999999], [1388530800000, 40441266.119999997], [1391209200000, 35620818.450000003], [1393887600000, 37668338.520000003], [1396306800000, 39715102.090000004]]}, {"data": [[1199142000000, 14348325.09], [1201820400000, 13382331.710000001], [1204498800000, 12556735.32], [1207004400000, 14411192.1], [1209679200000, 12366321.76], [1212271200000, 12310439.560000001], [1214949600000, 12895970.57], [1217541600000, 11070998.77], [1220220000000, 12230655.65], [1222898400000, 14247345.199999999], [1225490400000, 12139570.039999999], [1228172400000, 13450274.34], [1230764400000, 12712683.24], [1233442800000, 11440729.76], [1236121200000, 13210443.300000001], [1238540400000, 13378317.15], [1241215200000, 12275120.32], [1243807200000, 13059431.59], [1246485600000, 14022812.720000001], [1249077600000, 12362052.369999999], [1251756000000, 13319503.35], [1254434400000, 14224831.65], [1257026400000, 14108009.210000001], [1259708400000, 14794323.48], [1262300400000, 13135916.02], [1264978800000, 12838162.82], [1267657200000, 15040463.24], [1270076400000, 14684116.84], [1272751200000, 14344444.32], [1275343200000, 15445593.789999999], [1278021600000, 15934327.5], [1280613600000, 14780265.74], [1283292000000, 15637886.34], [1285970400000, 16199615.02], [1288562400000, 16912721.68], [1291244400000, 17460960.48], [1293836400000, 16166330.27], [1296514800000, 15392960.76], [1299193200000, 17262490.219999999], [1301612400000, 16456029.74], [1304287200000, 18237139.760000002], [1306879200000, 16302139.15], [1309557600000, 17259505.800000001], [1312149600000, 17083651.109999999], [1314828000000, 17054157.969999999], [1317506400000, 17535675.780000001], [1320098400000, 18170368.289999999], [1322780400000, 17774857.890000001], [1325372400000, 17589985.170000002], [1328050800000, 16466294.609999999], [1330729200000, 18419713.649999999], [1333234800000, 17640077.23], [1335909600000, 18012899.140000001], [1338501600000, 17565699.149999999], [1341180000000, 18430389.27], [1343772000000, 17968708.379999999], [1346450400000, 17468169.600000001], [1349128800000, 19527314.98], [1351720800000, 19315942.399999999], [1354402800000, 17956570.120000001], [1356994800000, 18006744.800000001], [1359673200000, 17552543.670000002], [1362351600000, 17788156.350000001], [1364770800000, 19442332.52], [1367445600000, 16896598.27], [1370037600000, 16507929.59], [1372716000000, 17986239.280000001], [1375308000000, 16375299.970000001], [1377986400000, 18584581.219999999], [1380664800000, 21502435.82], [1383256800000, 21521257.18], [1385938800000, 21818919.420000002], [1388530800000, 22204682.649999999], [1391209200000, 20352911.530000001], [1393887600000, 21483605.25], [1396306800000, 22480266.02]]}, {"data": [[1199142000000, 2983.3899999999999], [1201820400000, 2435.9200000000001], [1204498800000, 2682.1799999999998], [1207004400000, 3022.5], [1209679200000, 2354.23], [1212271200000, 2720.0500000000002], [1214949600000, 2331.0700000000002], [1217541600000, 2145.3699999999999], [1220220000000, 2390.1199999999999], [1222898400000, 2651.1199999999999], [1225490400000, 3306.4899999999998], [1228172400000, 3721.1500000000001], [1230764400000, 4135.6999999999998], [1233442800000, 2853.9000000000001], [1236121200000, 3282.8499999999999], [1238540400000, 2991.1500000000001], [1241215200000, 2613.6999999999998], [1243807200000, 2760.9499999999998], [1246485600000, 2920.1999999999998], [1249077600000, 2809.0], [1251756000000, 2472.1500000000001], [1254434400000, 3115.9000000000001], [1257026400000, 2916.9499999999998], [1259708400000, 4590.8000000000002], [1262300400000, 4615.6999999999998], [1264978800000, 3049.8000000000002], [1267657200000, 3898.5500000000002], [1270076400000, 3269.5500000000002], [1272751200000, 3743.8000000000002], [1275343200000, 2693.75], [1278021600000, 2679.3499999999999], [1280613600000, 3729.3000000000002], [1283292000000, 2821.9000000000001], [1285970400000, 2933.6999999999998], [1288562400000, 3871.9000000000001], [1291244400000, 4465.8500000000004], [1293836400000, 4060.0500000000002], [1296514800000, 2998.0999999999999], [1299193200000, 3798.9000000000001], [1301612400000, 3768.0500000000002], [1304287200000, 3003.5999999999999], [1306879200000, 3565.1500000000001], [1309557600000, 2491.3000000000002], [1312149600000, 2766.25], [1314828000000, 2652.5500000000002], [1317506400000, 2779.25], [1320098400000, 3173.3499999999999], [1322780400000, 3676.0], [1325372400000, 3734.25], [1328050800000, 4069.6500000000001], [1330729200000, 3698.6300000000001], [1333234800000, 3508.5700000000002], [1335909600000, 3328.3899999999999], [1338501600000, 2770.6900000000001], [1341180000000, 2985.0599999999999], [1343772000000, 3059.5500000000002], [1346450400000, 2717.0], [1349128800000, 3248.1799999999998], [1351720800000, 3495.0500000000002], [1354402800000, 4116.3199999999997], [1356994800000, 3573.96], [1359673200000, 3602.1700000000001], [1362351600000, 3743.7399999999998], [1364770800000, 3512.3400000000001], [1367445600000, 3028.48], [1370037600000, 2718.4299999999998], [1372716000000, 3126.1100000000001], [1375308000000, 2856.6199999999999], [1377986400000, 2752.0999999999999], [1380664800000, 3180.3200000000002], [1383256800000, 3238.1700000000001], [1385938800000, 4062.3699999999999], [1388530800000, 3387.9299999999998], [1391209200000, 3163.8099999999999], [1393887600000, 3458.52], [1396306800000, 3306.8099999999999]]}, {"data": [[1199142000000, 17884.799999999999], [1201820400000, 16487.549999999999], [1204498800000, 18079.200000000001], [1207004400000, 19597.950000000001], [1209679200000, 17532.450000000001], [1212271200000, 16038.0], [1214949600000, 14980.950000000001], [1217541600000, 16475.400000000001], [1220220000000, 15600.6], [1222898400000, 17095.049999999999], [1225490400000, 16888.5], [1228172400000, 16900.650000000001], [1230764400000, 16985.700000000001], [1233442800000, 133.65000000000001], [1236121200000, 18139.950000000001], [1238540400000, 11907.0], [1241215200000, 3207.5999999999999], [1243807200000, 1081.3499999999999], [1246485600000, 340.19999999999999], [1249077600000, 133.65000000000001], [1251756000000, 12.15], [1254434400000, 0.0], [1257026400000, 72.900000000000006], [1259708400000, 12.15], [1262300400000, 1275.75], [1264978800000, 12.15], [1267657200000, 2502.9000000000001], [1270076400000, 1142.0999999999999], [1272751200000, 340.19999999999999], [1275343200000, 3341.25], [1278021600000, 3073.9499999999998], [1280613600000, 729.0], [1283292000000, 3025.3499999999999], [1285970400000, 1871.0999999999999], [1288562400000, 3134.6999999999998], [1291244400000, 1579.5], [1293836400000, 3256.1999999999998], [1296514800000, 5212.3500000000004], [1299193200000, 3973.0500000000002], [1301612400000, 2259.9000000000001], [1304287200000, 255.15000000000001], [1306879200000, 5090.8500000000004], [1309557600000, 0.0], [1312149600000, 5783.3999999999996], [1314828000000, 2673.0], [1317506400000, 4945.0500000000002], [1320098400000, 97.200000000000003], [1322780400000, 5115.1499999999996], [1325372400000, 1749.5999999999999], [1328050800000, 0.0], [1330729200000, 2563.6500000000001], [1333234800000, 2988.9000000000001], [1335909600000, 2563.6500000000001], [1338501600000, 1713.1500000000001], [1341180000000, 1944.0], [1343772000000, 5394.6000000000004], [1346450400000, 0.0], [1349128800000, 2296.3499999999999], [1351720800000, 2940.3000000000002], [1354402800000, 3134.6999999999998], [1356994800000, 4045.9499999999998], [1359673200000, 4374.0], [1362351600000, 1458.0], [1364770800000, 2405.6999999999998], [1367445600000, 2369.25], [1370037600000, 72.900000000000006], [1372716000000, 5418.8999999999996], [1375308000000, 0.0], [1377986400000, 5467.5], [1380664800000, 1385.0999999999999], [1383256800000, 0.0], [1385938800000, 4143.1499999999996], [1388530800000, 0.0], [1391209200000, 3535.6500000000001], [1393887600000, 2101.9499999999998], [1396306800000, 267.30000000000001]]}, {"data": [[1199142000000, 1001.04], [1201820400000, 349.19999999999999], [1204498800000, 128.03999999999999], [1207004400000, 151.31999999999999], [1209679200000, 3.8799999999999999], [1212271200000, 488.88], [1214949600000, 527.67999999999995], [1217541600000, 298.75999999999999], [1220220000000, 566.48000000000002], [1222898400000, 997.15999999999997], [1225490400000, 543.20000000000005], [1228172400000, 1024.3199999999999], [1230764400000, 1001.04], [1233442800000, 737.20000000000005], [1236121200000, 508.27999999999997], [1238540400000, 360.83999999999997], [1241215200000, 438.44], [1243807200000, 337.56], [1246485600000, 419.04000000000002], [1249077600000, 325.92000000000002], [1251756000000, 353.07999999999998], [1254434400000, 457.83999999999997], [1257026400000, 636.32000000000005], [1259708400000, 442.31999999999999], [1262300400000, 403.51999999999998], [1264978800000, 2902.2399999999998], [1267657200000, 384.12], [1270076400000, 151.31999999999999], [1272751200000, 108.64], [1275343200000, 97.0], [1278021600000, 31.039999999999999], [1280613600000, 11.640000000000001], [1283292000000, 23.280000000000001], [1285970400000, 11.640000000000001], [1288562400000, -7.7599999999999998], [1291244400000, 23.280000000000001], [1293836400000, 11.640000000000001], [1296514800000, 0.0], [1299193200000, 0.0], [1301612400000, 0.0], [1304287200000, 3.8799999999999999], [1306879200000, 3.8799999999999999], [1309557600000, 0.0], [1312149600000, 0.0], [1314828000000, 0.0], [1317506400000, 0.0], [1320098400000, 0.0], [1322780400000, 0.0], [1325372400000, 0.0], [1328050800000, 0.0], [1330729200000, 0.0], [1333234800000, 0.0], [1335909600000, 0.0], [1338501600000, 0.0], [1341180000000, 0.0], [1343772000000, 0.0], [1346450400000, 0.0], [1349128800000, 0.0], [1351720800000, 0.0], [1354402800000, 0.0], [1356994800000, 0.0], [1359673200000, 0.0], [1362351600000, 0.0], [1364770800000, 0.0], [1367445600000, 0.0], [1370037600000, 0.0], [1372716000000, 0.0], [1375308000000, 0.0], [1377986400000, 0.0], [1380664800000, 0.0], [1383256800000, 0.0], [1385938800000, 0.0], [1388530800000, 0.0], [1391209200000, 0.0], [1393887600000, 0.0], [1396306800000, 0.0]]}]

Comment: How your data looks like?

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Sorry for late response. You can have sample data from here:
http://78.46.106.130:83/get_item_data_ios?generic={"show_total":true,"db_name":"NPI","measure":"1","timeoffset":433112400000,"line_ids":["268802","269201","268746","269507","269147"]}

Comment: It deosnt work for me, return error.

Comment: try again. stackoverflow doesn't add dictionary in url's query string. select whole url and paste it
http://78.46.106.130:83/get_item_data_ios?generic={"show_total":true,"db_name":"NPI","measure":"1","timeoffset":433112400000,"line_ids":["268802","269201","268746","269507","269147"]}

Comment: "DoesNotExist at /get_item_data_ios" error still. Plase paste a part of data here.

Comment: you may see demo data at the end of my question

Comment: At the beginning please sort your data, ascending by x, because its not.